# grape-api - Force empty string to set values to null

Tags: ruby-grape, grape-api

I am creating an API endpoint which contains a file upload field and a few string fields. My goal is to allow clients to clear values on those string fields, i.e. the DB should persist these values as `null`.

However, due to the fact that the request may contain files, the client should be setting the `Content-type` header to `multipart/form-data`. This implies that client cannot send a representation of "null", but can only send an empty string to indicate the intent of clearing the value for a given string field.

Is there a way for grape-api library to know that when it is receiving a multipart request it should be able to nullify blank string values in the params, or is there a better approach to what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
Grape.configure do |config|
  config.param_builder = Grape::Extensions::Hashie::Mash::ParamBuilder
end
```

you can override the param builder. extend the default one and override the [build_params](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/4c209284c701b3c1aafae67a5c7452f8c6879647/lib/grape/extensions/hashie/mash.rb#L15) method or monkey patch it.

```
params.transform_values {|v| v.eql?('') ? nil : v }
```